# ZX Spectrum interrupt handling: maskable and NMI

Tags: zx-spectrum, interrupt

Is there a skeleton for handling the interrupt on the ZX Spectrum? Can I read it?

I need the ZX Spectrum to handle an interrupt from a device and I have no idea where to start from.

I like the idea of handling a maskable interrupt, but it seems to already be used by the ULA. The other option would be the `/NMI` input, which I understand to be free for use.

Comment: You could argue that the NMI handling is a blunder, but maybe the spectrum developers decided that certain critical sections in the code would be unsafe if NMIs were allowed (for example midway through a device driver), so they made sure that NMI could only ever be equivalent to a reset.

Comment: @jrrk, the Spectrum ROM's NMI scheme wasn't the result of some deep planning session with a cryptic good idea coming out of it. It's pretty clearly just muck-up. Look into the history of the ZX Spectrum ROM development, it was done flat out for little reward by poor old Nine Tiles, as were its predecessors it evolves from. As I put in my answer below, *...no-one has been seen to have found an application for that (way of doing NMI) and publicised it in the last 40 years, so it can safely be called useless*. Most often, things really just are what they look like. No exciting backstory.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

To use the maskable interrupt request `/INT` on a Spectrum, you need a program that does the following:

- Implements your Interrupt Service Routine (ISR). This should include a `RST 56h` instruction to call the ROM's ISR so keyboard scanning etc. keeps working.
- Disables maskable interrupts with a `DI` instruction.
- Sets up an interrupt service address table in RAM on a page (256 byte) address boundary.
- Loads the I register with the high byte of the table address.
- Loads the table's highest vector (`xxFEh`) with your ISR address.
- Changes the Interrupt Mode to 2 with an `IM 2` instruction.
- Enables maskable interrupts with an `EI` instruction.

Because of a somewhat tragic mistake in the Spectrum's ROM software, the Non-Maskable Interrupt `/NMI` pin and function cannot be used, without extra hardware to overlay the existing ROM.

In the standard Spectrum, the idea was that the NMI ISR address would be stored in system variable `NMIADDR` and on an NMI the ROM would jump to `NMIADDR` unless it held `0000h` as an 'unused' marker. Tragically, the ROM's ISR at `0066h` gets the test upside-down: if `NMIADDR` is zero, it jumps to address `NMIADDR`, instead of if `NMIADDR` is non-zero.

That single mistake (a `JR NZ` instead of a `JR Z`) renders the Spectrum's NMI and `NMIADDR` useless. (It could be argued that it can be used to conditionally reset the Spectrum based on `NMIADDR`. But no-one has been seen to have found an application for that and publicised it in the last 40 years, so it can safely be called useless.)

Comment: Well, when you're fiddling with hardware anyways, you could do what the IF1 does - replace the Spectrum ROM entirely as reaction to RST8 - While the shadow ROM is paged in, *you* own he RST and interrupt vectors. Obviously, that could be a bit of a limitation.

Comment: @tofro, when you say 'fiddling with hardware' though, adding an overlay EPROM and programming it is far more work and cost than connecting a single wire up, it's not just a little extra. I know because I've built both for the Spectrum. Do it in software, nice and easy and that's what software's flexibility is for. I did this a load of times, too.

Comment: This answer is slightly wrong. There are circumstances where the value on the bus from the im2 int ack cycle will be random (it's also FF not FE) and your software will crash. Instead you point I at one of the page sized blocks of FF in the ROM, set FFFF to a JR, and put your code from FFF4.

Comment: @AlanCox pointing I into ROM will work to get an FFFF vector on the 48k ROM but not when the 128k ROM is paged-in (and with external hardware connected which may drive the data bus during INT-asserted) which doesn't have a 257-byte span of FF bytes, in that case I think the answer's method would be most portable between different Spectrum models and hardware, and even other Z80-based systems.

Comment: True but nobody ever needed the 128K ROM paged in for a game or the magic rst8 ball

Comment: @TonyM It is not a mistake, software houses that were given Speccy prototypes asked Sinclair to render the NMI routine useless  giving as a reason it could be used to hack software titles.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro, can you substantiate that idea with any evidence? That sounds very implausible because if Sinclair wanted to disable it, it'd be much better to replace it with a RETN or some NOPs and RETN, rather than what was done.

Comment: @TonyM Not "an ideia", facts. A large batch of (E)PROMs was already burnt, and they just changed a single bit for saving time/money, from JR Z to JR NZ, look at the Z80 instruction table. Typical of Sinclair cheap ideas and quick/clever thinking. It has been known folklore for ages, I honestly dont have the time to entertain your reasoning these days, please search for it yourself. I might have read about it two decades ago.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro, sorry, "facts" then "known folklore" says it. I'm very open to a substantiated explanation, and would like to find one, but you'd have to put forward actual docs or interviews from someone at Sinclair etc to do so. Searches inc. five Spectrum forums found a flat nothing on this. I can get someone once looked at JR xx opcodes and imagination ran. But just as easy and much simpler for Sinclair to NOP (00h) out the JP (HL) in programmed EPROM than play around with JR xx. (Don't get the "entertain your reasoning" bit, I'm afraid, assuming it's just friendly phrasing unusual to me.)

Comment: @TonyM Demanding proof of something someone read probably back in the day comes across as arrogant. So much more when you show you dont understand how EPROMs are programmed or erased. For those who know, and still lived those 80s wild west times, the story seems plausible enough.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro (a) Please let's stay away from personal/angry comments and stick with [Be Nice](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/help/behavior), thanks. (b) Asking for a claim to be somehow substantiated seems reasonable in engineering, nothing personal. I'm keen to find out the reason for the NMI handler. You said you weren't going to look into but I did put the time into looking for your idea and found absolutely nothing on it. It sounds like you're unable to find anything also and I'm afraid talk from decades ago can't be passed on as "fact", which you had.

Comment: (c) In 1984, I designed and built an EPROM programmer to handled about every part on the market (6.5/12/25/etcV) as our firm had a surplus of them. They scrapped 75,000 once-progd EPROMs a year, had a big programming facility. So I do understand programming/erasing EPROMs very well indeed and my NOP comment shows that, so I don't get your comment there. I'd also been low-level programming the Spectrum in assembly for years by then. (d) If you'd like to comment further, please do so in [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151706/room-for-tonym-and-rui-f-ribeiro) instead, thanks.

Answer (score 5):

I managed to bypass the firmware error with some *fiddling with [hardware](https://vitsoft.info/images/Elektronika1989-4str33.htm)* connected to the ZX Spectrum. Non-maskable interrupt was triggered manually with a pushbutton. No need to load any NMI driver, everything worked with the original ZX Spectrum ROM.

My hardware decoded the value `0068h` on address bus, which was activated whenever NMI request arrived. This value temporarily blocked ROMCS and at the same time forced **0** on data lines D4, D5. This simulated the instruction `CFh`, i.e. `RST 8`.

Unfortunately this solution doesn't work in mode IM2 (most games),
but it had saved me many times from having to reset during program development.

Whenever my computer got frozen, I pressed NMI pushbutton which activated maskable interrupt `RST 8` instead of NMI. That invoked the code `ERROR_RESTART`. Message `CONTINUE e, 30:1` appeared at the bottom and I could continue with Basic commands, keeping the memory unerased.

Comment: Very interesting.